# Java security InvalidKeyException ODL Netconf TestTool

Tags: java, opendaylight

I have deployed the ODL Netconf TestTool (netconf-testtool-1.1.0-Boron-executable.jar) onto my Nitrogen ODL Controller so I begin Netconf Testing.

When I launch the Netconf TestTool via java -Xmx1G -jar netconf-testtool-1.1.0-Boron-executable.jar I get the following output which seems correct.

```
root@Ubuntu:~# java -Xmx1G -jar netconf-testtool-1.1.0-Boron-executable.jar

 - 16:56:29.985 [main] INFO  o.o.n.t.tool.NetconfDeviceSimulator - Starting 1, SSH simulated devices starting on port 17830
 - 16:56:31.336 [main] INFO  o.a.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - Trying to register BouncyCastle as a JCE provider
 - 16:56:32.381 [main] INFO  o.a.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
 - 16:56:32.683 [main] INFO  o.o.n.t.tool.NetconfDeviceSimulator - All simulated devices started successfully from port 17830 to 17830
```

I then proceed to add a Netconf-Connector for the Netconf TestTool on the ODL Controller via REST, which is successful and it's reports the "connecting" status.

```
"node-id": "Netconf-Testtool",
"netconf-node-topology:host": "127.0.0.1",
"netconf-node-topology:connection-status": "connecting",
"netconf-node-topology:port": 17830
```

But when I look back at the ODL TestTool I see the following JAVA error

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you tried using the Nitrogen test tool instead?

Comment: Hi Stephen,

I may be wrong but I don't think there is a Nitrogen test tool, I've downloaded the tool from the below repository as suggested in the netconf tool guides.

https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/netconf/netconf-testtool/

Do you know of a Nitrogen Version?

Comment: The Nitrogen version is [1.3.1](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/netconf/netconf-testtool/1.3.1/) (yes, it’s not obvious...).

Comment: And the documentation is unfortunately out of date.

Comment: Formatting to make your question easier to read

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing using the netconf-test-tool from carbon (1.2.3-SNAPSHOT) and ODL Boron SR3 for the controller.

I found the reason is that my VM is using JDK 8 u161 where the tool is running and it looks like there was a change in u151 that changed a default keysize. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html

I pulled the netconf-testtool-1.3.2-executable.jar artifact from nexus like Stephen suggested and the problem has gone away and I can mount the simulator.

The SSH related dependencies on the 1.3.x version of the test tool were probably updated with a newer version of the JDK.